# Bind Polymer 2.x event handler to a global function?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-elements, polymer-2.0

I have some Polymer elements that are not inside an element/app, and I can't figure out how to attach their event handlers, such as `on-click`, to a global javascript function.

For example, let's say my code looks something like this

```
<head>
    // Import stuff...

    function login(){
        // Do stuff
    }
</head>
<body unresolved>    
    <dom-if id="signInItem">
        <template>
            <paper-button on-tap="login"><iron-icon icon="icons:account-circle"></iron-icon> &nbsp; Log in</paper-button>
        </template>
    </dom-if>
</body>
```

This won't work, because `on-tap` expects to bind to a property of an enclosing element (I guess). What are my options?

Comment: what about regular onclick="myFunction()" event, will that work out?

Answer (score 1):

give some id for paper-button

```
<paper-button id="button"></paper-button>
```

in javascript you can add eventlistener as shown below

```
    this.$.button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log("clicked");
     // write your code 
    });
```

or you can write your code in seperate function

```
ready() {
  super.ready();
  this.$.button.addEventListener('click', e => this.handleClick(e));
}
handleClick(e) {
   console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to fire a function not in polymer you may call;

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('login', { bubbles: true, composed: true, detail: true }));
```

This will fire your `login` listen in global js (ie. main.js) as below;

```
addEventListener('login', function (e) {
      // Do something for login 

})
```

EDIT:  I think you also need to change dom-if to dom-bind  in order to bind this code as its at root level

Answer (score 0):

You can always forward a call to a local class member function (MyElement.login) to a global namespace:

```
/* 1 */ class MyElement extends Polymer.Element {
/* 2 */     // ...
/* 3 */     
/* 4 */     login: (() => (evt) (MyGlobalNamespace || window).login.bind(this))()
/* 5 */ }
```

You can even omit the surrounding closure function - if you're not using `this` within the implementation of `login` -, simplifying line 4 to: `login: (MyGlobalNamespace || window).login`